# How to hide the Main window(parent) from pop up window in PyQt5.?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Main window from where I am calling Waiver window(popup). On clicking OK on Waiver popup, I want to close the Waiver pop up and hide the Main window. I have included self.parent().hide in waiver pop up but its throwing error "Process finished with exit code 1073741845" . The pop up closes and the main window terminates abruptly.

**waiver_window.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QRect


class popup_on_waiver(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(660, 340))
        self.setWindowTitle("Waiver")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.cb = QComboBox(centralWidget)
        self.cb.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 100, 30))
        self.cb.addItem("1")
        self.cb.addItem("2")
        self.cb.addItem("3")
        self.cb.addItem("4")
        self.cb.setObjectName("combobox")
        self.cb.move(80, 80)

        self.OK = QPushButton('OK',self)
        self.OK.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {font-size: 14px; font: Bold; font-family: Verdana; background-color: Orange; color: White}')
        self.OK.move(400,280)

        self.Cancel = QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        self.Cancel.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {font-size: 14px; font: Bold; font-family: Verdana; background-color: Orange; color: White}')
        self.Cancel.move(520, 280)

        vbox.addWidget(self.cb)
        vbox.addWidget(self.OK)
        vbox.addWidget(self.Cancel)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.OK.clicked.connect(self.hide_main)
        self.Cancel.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.show()

    def hide_main(self):
        self.close
        self.parent().hide()

    def waiverClicked(self):
        self.p = popup_on_waiver()
```

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt, QTimer
from gui_package.waiver_window import popup_on_waiver
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Waiver = QPushButton('Waiver', self)
        self.Waiver.clicked.connect(lambda: popup_on_waiver.waiverClicked(self))
        hbox.addWidget(self.Waiver)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Timesheet")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(""))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()
```

Comment: what is `waiverClicked`?

Comment: def waiverClicked(self):                                                                                               '''its a function in Waiver class that I am calling from Main window on button click to instantiate popup_on_waiver class'''
          self.p = popup_on_waiver()

Comment: I don't see that in your code, edit your question and add it there. Also take the time if there are other such errors. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: for some reason, its not letting me submit after editing. It gives error, your question is full of code, no description. kinda message

Comment: Add a more detailed explanation and there will be no such problem(more description).

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the popup window with a parent, so `self.parent()` returns None, and then you are trying to call `hide()` on an object that doesn't exist. The way you call the popup window, where you create an instance of the `popup_on_waiver` class *within the class itself*, is kind of strange. Additionally, it makes more sense for the popup to inherit from QDialog instead of QMainWindow. Now construct the popup widget inside the `Main` class **with parent `self`**, and connect the waiver button to the `QDialog.exec_()` method:

```
popup = popup_on_waiver(self)
self.Waiver.clicked.connect(popup.exec_)
```

Here is the edited code.

```
class popup_on_waiver(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(660, 340))
        self.setWindowTitle("Waiver")

        self.cb = QComboBox()
        self.cb.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 100, 30))
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4"])
        self.cb.setObjectName("combobox")
        self.cb.move(80, 80)

        self.OK = QPushButton('OK')
        self.OK.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {font-size: 14px; font: Bold; font-family: Verdana; background-color: Orange; color: White}')
        self.OK.move(400, 280)

        self.Cancel = QPushButton('Cancel')
        self.Cancel.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {font-size: 14px; font: Bold; font-family: Verdana; background-color: Orange; color: White}')
        self.Cancel.move(520, 280)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cb)
        vbox.addWidget(self.OK)
        vbox.addWidget(self.Cancel)

        self.OK.clicked.connect(self.hide_main)
        self.Cancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)

    def hide_main(self):
        self.accept()
        self.parent().hide()


class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.Waiver = QPushButton('Waiver')

        popup = popup_on_waiver(self)
        self.Waiver.clicked.connect(popup.exec_)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.Waiver)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Timesheet")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(""))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. But with this change, both main window and pop up dialog open at the same time. popup = popup_on_waiver(self) (this itself is opening the pop up)
self.Waiver.clicked.connect(popup.exec_). For readablity, I want to place popup dialog in separate file and import it in Main file. That should be fine right?

Comment: They don't open at the same time. The popup dialog opens when the button is clicked.